# Create html table with vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I would like to create this table and loop creating rows for an email template using vba:

```
<td width=254 nowrap style='width:190.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;background:#BDD7EE;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:16.5pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;color:black'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr></table>
```

I tried:

```
FullString = "<td width=254 nowrap style='width:190.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;background:#BDD7EE;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:16.5pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b><span style='font-family:""&""Times New Roman""&"",serif;color:black'>FirstName<o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr></table>"

ReplaceWith = "<td width=254 nowrap style='width:190.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;background:#BDD7EE;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:16.5pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b><span style='font-family:""&""Times New Roman""&"",serif;color:black'>James<o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><td width=254 nowrap style='width:190.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;background:#BDD7EE;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:16.5pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b><span style='font-family:""&""Times New Roman""&"",serif;color:black'>FirstNameReplace<o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr></table>"

oTemplate.HTMLBody = Replace(oTemplate.HTMLBody, FullString, ReplaceWith )
```

Nothing was replaced.

Comment: insert a table object into the email body

Answer (score 0):

I thnk you can follow this formula to replace

`.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "#recipient#", "Some other value")`

[more 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660647/outlook-vba-losing-formatting-with-replace-function-and-htmlbody-wont-work)

[more 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469960/send-an-email-from-excel-2007-vba-using-an-outlook-template-set-variables/8473313#8473313)

Comment: The reason I do the way I am doing is because I'm going to loop to recreate the keywords to be replaced if customer are more than one. The table contains a style that I need so the row will be recreate.

Comment: hii is this help   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886251/dynamically-create-html-table-rows-with-vba

Comment: not really, because I have my own email template that I'm going to use. I just need to know how I'm going to add additional rows.